# Python unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Tags: python, numpy

I worked on making functions for K Nearest Neighbors. I have tested each function separately and they all work well. However whenever I put them together and run `KNN_method`, it shows `unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'`. 
Here is my code:

```
def distance(p,point):
    import numpy as np
    value = np.sqrt(sum(np.power((p-point),2)))
    return(value)

def find_neighbors(p,list_of_points, k = 3):
    import numpy as np
    distances = np.zeros(list_of_points.shape[0])
    for i in range(list_of_points.shape[0]):
        distances[i]= distance(p,list_of_points[i])
    ind = np.argsort(distances)
    return(ind[0:k])

def majority_votes(votes):
    import random
    vote_result = {}
    for key in votes:
        if key in vote_result:
            vote_result[key] += 1
        else:
            vote_result[key] = 1
    final_list = []
    for (number, vote) in vote_result.items():
        if vote == max(vote_result.values()):
            final_list.append(number)
    Winner = random.choice(final_list)
    return(Winner)


def KNN_method(p , list_of_points , outcomes , k = 3):
    ind = find_neighbors(p , list_of_points , k) 
    Final = majority_votes(outcomes[ind])
    return(Final)
```

Comment: I hope this is just an exercise. Scipy already has optimized KNN functions and data structures. Also check out Leland McInnes's hdbscan talk from PyCon US 2016 and SciPy 2016. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AgPQ76RIi6A https://github.com/lmcinnes/hdbscan

Comment: Arrays, like lists, can't be used as dictionary keys.  They are mutable objects.  Strings and tuples are immutable, and work as keys.  Do you really need to use an array as a key?

Comment: It would help if you provided a sample input on which the problem can be reproduced, and specified which line threw the exception.

Answer (score 12):

Convert to tuple first.

```
hash(tuple(np.array([1,2,3,4])))
```

Comment: Even if it  *seem to work*, it is a terrible solution. The real problem in the OP's code is a logistic one, an array should almost never be the key of a dictionary. Consider `A` as a numpy array, if a single value in `A` changes it wont match with the same value it was originally assigned. In other words, unless you really really really know what you are doing (which doesn't seem to be the case from the OP's code), you should never use a mutable object (even if you can hash it) as keys for a dictionary.

Comment: I found a quick and easy solution for this. Thanks for you guys mentioning the mutable objects. I converted the votes in majority_votes to list(votes) which allows me to convert numpy array to a list. In this way, I can access to integers in the array and use it as keys in dictionary.

Thanks again !!

Comment: Hi @Cantarella I would really like to see the final solution you implemented because I am doing something similar and having the same error message... Thanks Alvis