# Why am I getting 'unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' in Python, when making a plot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot

I'm trying to simply make a plot for the equation written below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# 100 linearly spaced numbers
x = np.linspace(0,100,100)
y= 1/{np.exp(1/x)+1}

#plot the function
plt.plot(x,y, 'r')

#show the plot
plt.show()
```

But whenever I use this code, I get the message:

```
unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

I have searched for the reason for this but the solutions I have seen such as in [Python unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41436542/python-unhashable-type-numpy-ndarray), doesn't seem to be the same as mine.

How can I correct this and avoid it happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using brackets where you should not use it. You need to replace

```
y= 1/{np.exp(1/x)+1}
```

by this

```
y= 1/(np.exp(1/x)+1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I haven't used python in a very long time and seem to have forgotten it all

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.